# Webpack Load DLL Dynamically

Tags: javascript, webpack

I am using `DllPugin` and `DllReferencePlugin` and everything works as intended.

Recently I tried to load a DLL *dynamically*.

The normal approach to load a chunk dynamically would be to use `require.ensure`:

```
require.ensure([], function() {
   var m = require("dll/mymodule");
   // ...
});
```

However, this just creates another chunk instead of loading the DLL.

I am wondering how DLLs can be loaded dynamically?